# Mobile Template problems

Tags: html, css

Having trouble with the background images while scrolling on a mobile device. The images work fine while Inspecting the website and setting it to mobile view, but when I use an actual mobile device the images are zoomed in and blurry.

Im having trouble with the navigation too when Im on a page post.. I cant get back to the main page since the nav links are anchored to the main page in specific spots.

Any help would be amazing! Thanks

http://www.wearesettv.com/

Comment: Not sure whether it will help, but I see few errors in console. It would be great to fix them

Comment: Do you have a meta `viewport` tag defined? e.g: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError it's easy to check...

Comment: Actually I couldn't reproduce the problem on my Samsung A7. It shows images pretty nicely as it should be(centered, but in actual size without zooming/blurring)

Comment: @Sergey Oooooh, there's the link... just sitting there in the open, not looking inconspicuous at all. Mystery how I missed that.

Comment: @Sergey I am using an iPhone. and tried it in the chrome browser also.. still had no change. Im glad to hear it works on android though. so there must be a problem with viewing it on iphone

Comment: Perhaps it could help https://support.invisionapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/204660949-Why-are-my-images-in-iOS-blurry-